# Windows 2008 Task Scheduler Return Code and Matlab Script

Tags: windows, matlab, scheduled-tasks

How do I allow my Matlab script to pass back a return code to the Task Scheduler?  I currently have a task that runs "matlab -r myscript".  The problem is the Task Scheduler always succeeds immediately after starting, even though myscript takes several minutes to run.  So, I don't see how to pass back an error code.

How can I make Task Scheduler wait until the script stops running and then get matlab to pass back a return code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `matlab -wait` command line option to have it block until the program is finished.

There appears to be an undocumented argument to `quit()` to set the exit status - e.g. `quit(42)` - which then shows up in %ERRORLEVEL%. Since it's undocumented, you might not want to rely on it. Alternatively, have your script write its status to a file and have a wrapper script parse it.